# what does following sql code do?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

guys i have seen following code   in internet

```
select round(abs(months_between(sysdate,add_months(hire_date,12*(round((months_between(sysdate,hire_date)/12)))))))
from employees
```

unfortunately there was not enough  information  if what does it do,i have run this command in my oracle 11.g database,and seen  if of numbers,like  `6,5,4,7,3,2`

```
5
2
1
1
6
5
2
2
3
```

like this ,please i know functions,just can't determine it's  usage  here,what  represent this  numbers?please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working from the inside out:-

```
round( (months_between(  sysdate,  hire_date)   /12)
```

Gets the number of complete years the employee has been employed

```
  add_months( hire_date,12 * (years calculated above )
```

Gets the date the employee completed n complete years since being employed

```
round(abs(months_between( sysdate, date employee completed n years )
```

Gets the number of months till the next full year of employment.

No idea why!

Comment: @dato if this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like " MOD(months_between(hire_date,sysdate),12) " would get the same number with less fuss.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems to me, that one would calculate the number of month until the next full year based on hire date is reached. It could also be the last point when a full year is reached, depending on which time point is closer to now.

- first he calculated the diff between current date and hire date and rounds it to full years
- then he adds the years (transformed into number month) to the hire date, so this date will be the next time point when a full year of employment is reached
- at least he calculates the number of month between the next (or last) time point between now and a full year of employment

I think the following statement should give you the same result:

```
select abs(month_between(sysdate,hire_date)) % 12
```

Answer (score 0):

this was just getting the absolute and rounded up difference from hire date of an employee to current date. it just compares the current date and the hire date